# How to change the color of an inline svg in Angular?

Tags: angular, svg

I am not the familiar with SVGs. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-inline-svg to display an inline SVG.

**How can I change the color for this?**

I have searched through stack overflow and can't seem to find anything that works.

```
<span [inlineSVG]="'./assets/media/icons/svg/Navigation/Angle-double-left.svg'"></span>
```

Comment: Try `span ::ng-deep svg {  fill: red; }` (where you need to change the `span` to something more robust, like class name)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your class on `span`

```
<span class="my-color" [inlineSVG]="'./assets/media/icons/svg/Navigation/Angle-double-left.svg'"></span>
```

Then a simple color CSS should also work

```
.my-color {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked

```
<span class="svg-icon" [inlineSVG]="'./assets/media/icons/svg/Navigation/Angle-double-left.svg'"></span>
```

And on your CSS file:

```
.svg-icon ::ng-deep svg path {
    fill: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this with `setSVGAttributes`:

```
<span [inlineSVG]="'./assets/media/icons/svg/Navigation/Angle-double-left.svg'" [setSVGAttributes]="{ fill: 'red' }"></span>
```